# Has the spread of English removed any phonemes or characteristics from pre-existing languages?

Tags: english, historical-linguistics, etymology

I know there's already an answered question on here about English adding sounds and characteristics to languages, but I was wondering if there were many examples of the removal of intricacies from pre-existing languages (long standing ones, that weren't derived from English originally). I'm not educated in linguistics at all, so this might not make any sense.

Comment: Languages evolve and can lose this or that characteristic but I have never heard of one language **doing that** to another.

Comment: @Lambie - Just a couple of examples of one language doing that to another: 1) the usage of polysynthetic constructions in Guaraní is decreasing due to the influence of Spanish; 2) the two Sorbian languages are the only Slavic language where the uvular [ʁ] is the standard realization of /r/, they lost the alveolar trill [r] due to the the influence of German.

Comment: @YellowSky And that /r/ spreading in German dialects is an outside influence too.

Comment: The prime candidates here would be Welsh, Irish and Scottish Gaelic, native American languages of the US and Canada, including places like Hawaii and Samoa, and certain varieties of Spanish and French, and languages like Pennsylvania Dutch, Yiddish and Gullah, and various Creoles.

Comment: Plausible I'd say. I read/heard recently that Basque used to have a sound system less similar to Spanish but that it moved very close to Spanish due to the spread/influence/etc of the latter. I seem to recall also hearing that Estonian pronunciation is moving toward some more typical European features and away from Finnish. These anecdotes would suggest it's a general language process. I'd say the changes are often bidirectional though and would expect some of the changes in the sounds of English are due to contact as it spread.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, English is at least partially responsible for the loss of aspirated consonants in Swahili.

The most conservative dialects of Swahili have a four-way contrast between prenasalized, voiced, voiceless, and aspirated stops (`ⁿd d t tʰ`), but most dialects have now merged the aspirated and voiceless stops, losing the distinction between (e.g.) *taa* "lamp" and *tʰaa* "skate (type of fish)". Given the long contact between Swahili and English, which doesn't contrast voiceless and aspirated stops, I would attribute this at least in part to English influence.

Comment: What is your reference for that?

Comment: @Lambie As I said, "off the top of my head"

Comment: It would seem to be comparatively common among trading languages with large numbers of nonnative speakers.